# Receiving "no CustomObject named DandBCompany found" when Installing SFDX Unlocked Package

Tags: salesforcedx, permission-sets, unlocked-package, system-permissions

I'm working on publishing a Unlocked Package. I am using a developer org as a devhub and devloping using SFDX, VS Code, Scratch Orgs, etc... I am able to package the code without a problem, but when attempting to install it on another org (Internal Org) I am getting the following error:

```
Encountered errors installing the package!,Installation errors: 
1) (Demo_Component_Manager) In field: object - no CustomObject named DandBCompany found, Details: Demo_Component_Manager: In field: object - no CustomObject named DandBCompany found
```

This is referring to the Permission Set, which does not reference DandBCompany. The destination org does not have DandBCompany.

[Component Package Manager Repo](https://github.com/davidlarrimore/gpbu-component-package-manager)

When I originally deployed the Unlocked Package, there was a DandBCompany permission in the permission set, but that has since been removed. I have searched for any references of DandB in my project and found none (other than in the .sfdx folder that tracks all the objects in the Scratch org). I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Do you have the related permissions enabled in your Scratch Org Configuration File? This would cause the problem, even if you have no actual references in your Permission Set.

Comment: @sfdcfox - When I first created the package, I had a permission in my permission set, but it was wiped. I couldn't find any other references to DandB (D&B) in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is the deal. Since My component is using the Tooling API, my permission set had "View All Data" permission. While my permission set did not have anything specific to DandBCompany in it, the SFDX Packaging command clearly takes objects into account when packaging things up. It was automatically adding permissions to objects that the destination org did not have.

TLDR: Don't include "View All Data" permission in your permission set. It comes with a lot of baggage.

Answer (score 1):

The scratch org definition file needs to have the `edition` param set to **Enterprise** instead of **Developer**.

Answer (score 0):

Like sfdcfox said, you are not having **DataComDnbAccounts** &/or **DataComFullClean** in your config file.

Here - https://github.com/davidlarrimore/gpbu-component-package-manager/blob/master/config/project-scratch-def.json

Please check documentation on the same - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_datacomdnbaccounts

Also make sure that you give that config file as a parameter while creating the package. Then it'll work smooth.

Comment: I don't want anything related to data.com in my package. Thats the problem. I'm not using data.com, but somehow DandBCompany is still being referenced when it is packaged.

Comment: Can you search is there any related metadata is being used in your folder/profile

Comment: I have tried using the scratch-def when deploying the package and that did not help

Comment: When I originally deployed the package their was a permission set item related to D&B (DandBCompany) that has since been removed.